# cómo generó dos gráficos separados con matplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

quiero ver la dispersión de los datos en dos gráficos separados con matplot pero no lo consigo, alguien que amablemente me ayuda?

```
x = dts['HS']
y = dts['HC']
x1 = dts['AS']
y1 = dts['AC']

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('tiros')
plt.ylabel('corners')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una figura con múltiples gráficos con ayuda de la función `plt.subplots()` de la siguiente manera:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))
```

Así, le estaríamos indicando que deseamos una figura con `1` columna y `2` filas para introducir los respectivos gráficos, cada uno con un tamaño de `(10, 5)` y cada subgráfico sería almacenado en las variables `ax1` y `ax2`. Ya con esto sería suficiente poder mostrarlos en una misma ventana. Aquí te dejo el respectivo código de como debería quedar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Primer subgráfico
x = dts['HS']
y = dts['HC']
ax1.scatter(x, y)
ax1.grid()
ax1.set_xlabel('tiros')
ax1.set_ylabel('corners')

# Segundo subgráfico
x1 = dts['AS']
y1 = dts['AC']
ax2.scatter(x1, y1)
ax2.grid()
ax2.set_xlabel('tiros')
ax2.set_ylabel('corners')

plt.show()
```

Comment: disculpa (estoy aprendiendo), y si quisiera agregarle la linea del error cuadrático como seria? tengo esto para la primera línea plt.plot(x,y_regr,'r')